# Infopath 2010 SharePoint 2010: Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-enterprise, dropdown

I'm looking for a solution of the following question.

I have a mainlist with information about people.

---

List:

**Name -- OrgaLevel1 -- OrgaLevel2**

Wilson -- ... -- ...

---

I have also a list with the organisation of a company:

---

List:

**OrgaLevel1 -- Orgalevel2**

Orga A -- Orga AA Orga A -- Orga AB Orga B -- Orga BA Orga B -- Orga BA

---

I like to build the form for the mainlist like this

Name:

OrgaLevel1:

OrgaLevel2:

The values of the OrgaLevel2-DropDown should depend of the value I've selected in the OrgaLevel2-DropDown.

So if I selected OrgaA there should only be Orga AA and Orga AB in the second DropDown-List.

I hope, I have explained my problem understandable?! I can imagine, that this problem is quite easy but right now my synapse had a blockade.
Solutions like http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com/ are in our environment not possible.

Comment: Why not possible (e.g. only sandbox web parts) as this may have impact on what solutions people can propose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide will help you. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2004/03/24/95529.aspx

Comment: OK, I found a way to solve the problem with sharepoint lists: http://bit.ly/wNvqdK and sorry, it is in german. I will try to translate this the next days.